# How to hide this overflow content correctly?

Tags: html, css

```js
$('.child_1').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('left').siblings().toggleClass('left');
});
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.parent {
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.child_1 {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,0,.6);
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all .5s;
}
.child_1.left {
  width: 30%;
}
.child_2 {
  width: 70%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  left: 100%;
  transition: all .5s;
}
.child_2.left {
  left: 30%;
}
.child_2 > div {
  background-color: rgba(0,255,255,.6);
  height: 200px;
}  

.child_2 > div > div {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.relative {
  position: relative;
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Relative</p>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child_1"></div>
  <div class="child_2 relative">
    <div>Content of child_2<div></div></div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr />
<p>Absolute</p>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child_1"></div>
  <div class="child_2 absolute">
    <div>Content of child_2<div></div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I encounter this trouble:

1. Parent div must have overflow of hidden to hide child_2 when child_2 is moved out of parent;
2. Parent div can't have a declared height because the height of the child_2 is unknown(thought it is given in my example).

To hide child_2 div, I have tried two ways:

1. The first one is relatively positioned child_2, while as you can see, the content of child_2 is pushed to a wrong position;
2. The second one is absolutely positioned child_2, but an absolutely positioned element can't expand the height of parent element, so when parent div is given a hidden overflow value, the content of child_2 is cut.

Comment: Could you please give more details? I read your question thrice and didn't get what is your requirement.

Comment: @CharanKumar I have edited my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.child_1').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('left').siblings().toggleClass('left');
});
});
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.parent {
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
}
.child_1 {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,0,.6);
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all .5s;
}
.child_1.left {
  width: 30%;
}
.child_2 {
  width: 70%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  left: 100%;
  transition: all .5s;
}
.child_2.left {
  left: 30%;
}
.child_2 > div {
  background-color: rgba(0,255,255,.6);
  height: 200px;
}  

.child_2 > div > div {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.relative {
  position: relative;
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sample.css">
</head>

<body style="display:table">
    <p>Relative</p>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child_1"></div>
        <div class="child_2 relative">
            <div>1
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <p>Absolute</p>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child_1"></div>
        <div class="child_2 absolute">
            <div>1
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have added height to parent div, then overflow works fine

Comment: The height of parent div can't be declared because the height of child_2 is unknown(though it is given in my example ).

Comment: In order for the overflow property to have an effect, the block level container must either have a bounding height (height or max-height) or have white-space set to nowrap.

Comment: Or may be you can calculate height and set dynamically in your script when you can't declare it.